# Display Error: Multiple root elements

Tags: sharepoint-online, display-template

The following code is automatically being added to end of some Display Templates during a process in which i Export them using either the browser or SP Designer and the Import of them into another site collection resulting in multiple root element error.

This is the code that shows up under my closing html tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var g_duration = 446;
var g_iisLatency = 3;
var g_requireJSDone = new Date().getTime();
</script>
```

Anyone know how or why this is happening? Suggestions?

Thanks
-schuess